# angularjs md-select scrolling body issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am changing a ui from angularjs bootstrap3 to angularjs material. My selects work, md-select, but the options list comes up and the user is able to scroll the page behind itbwhile the options list stays in place.

I thought it had something to do with the md-scroll-mask z-index and the md-select-menu-container z-index but I have not been able to fix it completely. I can get it to not scroll by changing the z-indexes but then I cannot click outside the options list to hide it.

```
<md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="patientType" ng-change="updatePatientList(patientType)">
        <md-option value="ALL">All</md-option>
        <md-option value="ADMITTED">Admitted</md-option>
        <md-option value="PENDING">Pending</md-option>
        <md-option value="TRANSFER">Transfer</md-option>
        <md-option value="DISCHARGED">Discharged</md-option>
        <md-option value="NON-ADMIT">Non-Admit</md-option>
    </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
```

I need it to work like the State input here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

I am more of a designer so I am asking here and will get some help tomorrow from a developer.

Comment: When you're showing the drop down, can you inspect the page and look for the md-backdrop.  That should be covering your entire page, if not the scroll event will get through to the md-content below.

Comment: thank you, I had css on the body tag that caused the issue. I will need to post what it was later. I had added this css to fix a scrolling to top issue with the md-select.